# Basic discrete probability

Tags: probability-distributions

This is ***a very*** basic question in probability, but I would like a rigorous answer nevertheless.

When a text describes a random experiment, say,

- "With probability $p$ we assign $0$ to $x_1$, and otherwise we assign $1$, and independently with probability $r$ we assign $0$ to $x_2$ and otherwise we assign $1$."

**Question:** How do we then define the probability distribution in terms of sample space $\Omega$, and the axioms of probability. In particular, how do we know that
$$\sum_{e\in\Omega}\mathbf{Pr}\left[ e\right]  =1  ?$$
Especially, when we are in the general case of $n$ such independent experiments, each chosen with probability $p_i$, $i\in[n]$.
I understand that this can be computed and evaluated to 1, but is this the only "proof" of this fact? And how is this distribution called?

Comment: Question is confusing.  First example $P(x_1=0)=p$ then automatically $(x_1=1)=1-p$.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  There are only four events, right?  $00, 01, 10, 11$.  Just work out the probabilities of each and add.  I guess we are meant to assume independence, though you didn't specify that.

Comment: @lulu, correct. Added independence. But the question is just an example of the general scenario. What if I have the general case: $n$ such experiments each with $p_i$ probability, chosen independently. Is this direct computation of the sum of the probabilities the only proof? How is this distribution/experiment called?

Comment: Prove it inductively using the same calculation.  I doubt it is the *only* proof, but it's clear and straight forward.

Comment: @lulu, is this the established textbook proof? What's the name of this distribution/experiment?

Comment: I think this is too basic to be called an established textbook proof.  I suppose I'd call it the product distribution or joint distribution (so as not to confuse it with the distribution on the product of two variables).

Comment: @lulu, yes, probably the product distribution. How do I search for the properties of this product distribution? (Actually, I think this is probably called a Bernouli trial..?)

Comment: I think you'll have better luck searching for the [Joint Probability Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution).  If you search for the product, I expect you'll mostly get information on the product of two random variables.

Comment: @lulu, correct. That's what wiki gives.